# How to stretch this CSS menu to 100%

Tags: html, css, menu, css-tables

Here's a fantastic [CSS menu](http://www.devinrolsen.com/wp-content/themes/dolsen/demos/css/infinite-sub-menu/):

The only disadvantage its not stretched to 100%... if it has 2 elements, it should be 50%/50%, if 4 items then 25%/25%/25%/25% just like they were table cells. How to do that? I'm new to CSS.

Comment: You can use display: table;, display: table-row;, display: table-cell;, etc. to simulate table cell style widths if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table/table-cell` (for modern browsers and IE8+) and [display-table.htc](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/) (for IE6/7).

Comment: @chifliiiii What exactly about submenu?

Comment: Never mind i found a solution. When you have a submenu positioned absoluted in a table-cell li it won't work. So the solution is simple wrap the li contents in a div

Answer (score -1):

Modify its width as `100%` will make the menu span to full width.

```
#myfantasticmenu { width: 100%; }
```

I simulated the change with firebug and the needed Style defination was

```
#nav {
    overflow: hidden; /* To clear the div */
    width: 100%;
}
```

And about the part, where you need 50/50 for two and 25 each when the item are 4, you will require some javascript to do so.

If you consider using jQuery then it will something like

```
childs= $("#myfantasticmenu").children('a'); //grab the list items
childs.css('width', (100/childs.length)+%);
```

---

If avoiding scripting is your **MAJOR** target, then bring tables into the games, they *automatically* do the behavior you need.

Comment: well hopefully I will be able to avoid this :)

Comment: You suggested using JavaScript (and jQuery) and improper HTML to do something CSS can do.

Comment: It's improper to use a table for a simple navigation, and suggesting JavaScript at all when ordinary CSS can do it is not great, and suggesting jQuery at all when JavaScript can do it is also not great. I found your question the least useful and downvoted at as per http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down - it's nothing personal.

Comment: That you have asked that suggests you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of HTML.  HTML's purpose is not laying things out, but indicating meaning.  http://w3.org/tr/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.1 (6th paragraph)  *CSS*'s purpose is styling HTML (including laying things out).

Comment: From a purely visual perspective they aren't bad for layouts at all, but it's clear what HTML's purpose is, and it's clear what the table element's purpose is (not for a list of navigation items).